# efficient way to get deleted documents

Tags: cloudant

I'm searching for an efficient way to get the list of documents deleted in a Cloudant database.

Background: I have a Cloudant database containing 4 million records. The business logic allows also documents to be deleted. Data from this database is loaded daily into a SQL data warehouse and needs to be also marked as deleted.

A full reload is no option since it takes too long. Also querying the _changes stream seems not to scale well if the Cloudant database contains so many documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `_changes` feed and apply a server-side filter function (http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html) to eliminate all documents that don't have the `_deleted`property set. Your change feed listener would therefore only be notified whenever a DELETE operation is reported and network traffic kept to a minimum.